# VC++ project using unmanaged DLL in a multi-project solution causes linking errors when building

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a very strange problem with a multi-project solution in VS 2010. I had a solution with a single project in C++/CLR which interfaced a third-party unmanaged DLL. Now, I moved this project into a multi-project solution. I double-checked that all include / additional library parts are correct (I have this problem even when I set the absolute paths to the include and lib dir) and the `.lib` accompanying the third-party DLL is correctly referenced.

Now, when trying to build the project, I get a bunch of LNK2028, LNK2019, LNK2020 and the like.

However, when I create a single solution with only this project, it builds fine.

Does VS2010 not support multi-project solutions when one project references unmanaged code?

EDIT: I investigated some more, here is what happens:

1. Opening the project in a single solution => Builds fine.
2. Adding the very same project to an existing solution => Linker errors
3. Adding a new project to the solution with the single VC++ project => Builds fine.

Comment: Compare Configuration Properties --> C/C++ --> Command Line in the 2 scenarios and also Configuration Properties --> Linker --> Command Line. Are there any differences?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but unfortunately, there are not any differences. I can even build the project in a single solution, but adding it to a multi-project solution causes the linker errors. I think I will do a more hackish attempt - start from the solution where it builds and add the other projects to it until it fails.

Comment: Could you post some of the errors to give us some idea ?

Comment: This is unfortunately impossible, since the third-party DLL is internal, and posting error messages would expose some of its API I am not allowed to publish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*bangs head on keyboard* I finally solved it! It has nothing to do with the location of the project! I noticed that the solution built correctly when using `Release` configuration, but `Debug` causes the linker errors. It turned out that I tried to link against my third-party `.lib` file for Release mode in Debug mode. I changed the debug settings to use the debug-mode lib file in Debug mode and now it builds.